# Relationship between Random variable ,population and sample.

Tags: probability, estimation

I am trying to understand this, first, let me define it then I have to construct an example to understand this, please let me know if my intuition is correct or not. Thanks.

A statistical population consists of all the measurements of interest in
a statistical investigation. Usually, a population is described by a random
variable $X$. If we can gain some knowledge about the probability density
function $f(x; θ)$ of $X$, then we also gain some knowledge about the population
under investigation.

A sample is a portion of the population usually chosen by method of
random sampling and as such it is a set of random variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$
with the same probability density function $f(x; θ)$ as the population. Once
the sampling is done, we get
$X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, · · · , X_n = x_n$
where $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ are the sample data.

Okay so I am trying to understand the above definitions,
Suppose we have a population of 6 people namely $A, B, C, D, E,F.$ and we have a random variable $X$ which is the salaries of these 5 peoples suppose $X=100\$,200\$,300\$,400\$,500\$,600\$ $ be the corresponding salaries of $A, B, C, D, E, F$ respectively.

Suppose we want to know the average salary of the population. Choose a sample of size 2.$S=\{A,D\}$ then we have a random variable $X_1,X_4$ such that $X_1(A)=100\$$ and $X_4(D)=400\$$ so $S=\{X_1,X_4\}$ is it correct?

Comment: You have a population of size 6 and you sample 2 of them, yes.  Typically (if you're trying to figure out the pop. average) you'd average the two observed values to get \$250.  That would be your sample mean.  But here you know the pop mean is \$350, so you see that the sample mean can be off.

Comment: Actually I am trying to understand the definitions with the help of this example,can you tell me is my construction is correct? Likewise we can construct more samples to get the average salary

Comment: Your example is fine, but doesn't mention $f$.  Can you think of how to enhance your example by specifying $f$?

Comment: At the end you abuse the meaning of $S$, which you first said was the sample set $\{A,D\}$, a subset of the entire population.  So it isn't correct to say $S = \{X_1,X_4\}$ as that is collection of two random variables (whereas $\{A,D\}$ is not random at all).

Answer (score 2):

First, there is a subtle difference between the $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ and the $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. Depending on the book you use/the teacher you have, you may only ever see $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, or you may only ever see $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, or you could see both.

The capital letters $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are random variables (which are functions). In this setting, each of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ has the same distribution as $X$. They are not individual numbers. The lower case letters $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ *are* individual numbers. Conceptually, you can think about $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ as being the values *before* measurement/observation, and $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are the values *after* measurement/observation. So if $X$ represents the heights of people in the world, $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ could represent the heights of a random sample of people who have yet to be measured. Once we measure their heights and we have specific numbers, we use $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. This difference is somewhat subtle, and sometimes doesn't matter.

There is another issue. It seems to me that you're mixing the random sample with the probability space. You have a probability space $\Omega=\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$ with six possible outcomes. The random variable $X$ is a function $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $X(A)=100$, $\ldots$, $X(F)=600$.

If we wanted a sample of size $2$, we would typically denote this by $X_1, X_2$. The indices $1,2$ are numbering the random variables. The indices $1,2$ (or your indices $1,4$) do not have anything to do with the first and fourth values ($A$ and $D$) from the probability space $\Omega$. Similarly, when we choose a random sample, we aren't choosing a subset of $\Omega$, which is what you have with $S=\{A,D\}$. In this context, a random sample is not a subset of the probability space. It is a sequence of independent, identically distributed random variables. Consequently, each one is a random variable (which is a function) defined on all of $\Omega$. This is where the initial subtle point comes in, because sometimes rather than choosing a sequence of random variables, we are assuming a sequence of realized values from that sequence. This could look like the values $A,D$, in your example. But it could also look like $A,A$. So choosing two realizations (that is, obtaining two actual values from the probability space by measurement/observation) is not the same thing as choosing two values from the probability space.

Comment: Thanks ,One doubt as you said that $X$ is the height of the world and $X_1,...X_n$ represent the height of the random sample of the people who have yet to be measured.But aren't we already measured their height in the population? So we already have the measured values?Can you correct me if I am thinking wrong here>

Comment: "But aren't we already measured their height in the population?" No. If the population distribution is normal with mean $6$ feet and standard deviation $.25$ feet, this doesn't include the heights of any individual people. No ones heights are measured yet.

Comment: Even if we said there are three different heights that people can be (5 feet, 6 feet, and 7 feet, with probabilities .25, .5, .25), $X_1$ isn't the height of a specific person. It's a random variable. $X_1$ has a probability of .25 of being 5 feet, a probability of .5 of being 6 feet, and a probability of .25 of being 7 feet. 

It's only when we go get an actual person and measure their height that we get $x_1$, and that is a measured value.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realization_(probability)

Comment: But how we got mean and standard deviation without any data?

Comment: You can propose a mean and standard deviation by hypothesis. Saying the distribution is normal with mean 6 feet and standard deviation .25 feet is a model, and you can supply whatever values you want to your model. It's just that if your values are not close to the truth, your model will be of little value.

We can also select a normal distribution with mean 6 feet and standard deviation by measuring some people's actual heights. But 

1. We won't measure every person's height
2. The $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are still random variables, not heights of individual people.

Comment: so you mean if suppose I have chosen my sample of three people $A,B, C$ and let I actually measured the height of all these three persons in the sample let those heights are $x_1,x_2,x_3$ then $X_1(A)=x_1,X_2(B)=x_2,X_3(C)=x_3$, is that correct?

Comment: This is exactly right if my probability space is a discrete list of people (all the people in the world, for example). I would just add that it could be the case that the members $A,B,C$ of the probability space are not individual people. In particular, if I'm assuming the height is normally distributed, then the probability space (which is the domain on which the random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are defined) won't be a set of individuals. It could be something much more abstract.

Comment: I think I have a better example than the height example. Suppose we have a fair coin. The outcomes are $H$ and $T$ (heads or tails), each with probability .5. Suppose that I will win $1$ if the outcome is $H$ and $0$ otherwise. Suppose that we will flip the coin three times. Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be the outcomes of the flips *before* they occur. These are random variables, and before any flips, we can ask what is the probability that I win at least $2$? Before the flips, we have no $x_1,x_2,x_3$ values. $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ are random variables.

Comment: Once I flip the coins, I will get $x_1, x_2, x_3$. If we happen to observe the outcome $HHT$, we will have $x_1=x_2=1$, $x_3=0$. We will also have $x_1=X_1(HHT)$, $x_2=X_2(HHT)$, and $x_3=X_3(HHT)$. This is because the outcome is a set of results of three flips ($HHT$). By independence, it would be fine to say $x_1=X_1(H)$, $x_2=X_2(H)$, and $x_3=X_3(T)$, but formally $X_1,X_2,X_3$ depend on the joint result $HHT$.

Comment: Choosing a sample of size three is distinct from choosing a three element subset of the probability space, because the probability space is $\{H,T\}$, which has no three element subsets.